# customising GORM basic collections

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

As well as associations between different domain classes, GORM also supports mapping of basic collection types. . For example, the following class creates a nicknames association that is a Set of String instances

```
class Person {
    static hasMany = [nicknames:String]
}
```

This will store the nicknames in a separate table `person_nicknames`:

```
---------------------------------------------
| person_id         |     nickname          |
---------------------------------------------
|   1               |      Fred             |
---------------------------------------------
```

By default both columns are nullable and there are no indices present. I would like to make the following changes

- make both columns not null
- put a composite unique index on `(person_id, nickname)`

Obviously I could just run an SQL script to make these changes, but is it possible for me to express this in the domain model, so that GORM does it when creating and updating the schema?

Comment: I can't find a way to do it (without making a Nickname domain class and Person having many of them instead of String).  This might be a Q for the user-list?

Comment: @tim_yates I snuck in a question about this at the end of this (related) bug report http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9542

Comment: @tim_yates vote early and often!

Comment: As Tim mentioned, currently it seems there is no other way than solving this issue with a separate domain class:

    class Nickname {

        static belongsTo = [person: Person]

        String name

        static constraints = {
            name unique: 'person'
        }
    }

just in case someone needs a workaround for this issue.

Comment: @AndreSteingress yes, but I'm using this feature precisely because I don't want to create a doman class

Comment: @Don yep, thats what I figured. I just wanted to mention how to define the unique constraint for folks who need a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

No, this presently isn't possible.  You can fake it by making Nickname an explicit domain class (Andre Steingress gives an example in the question comments), but otherwise you have to write a migration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use joinTable and basic collection types.

http://grails.org/doc/2.4.3/ref/Database%20Mapping/joinTable.html

You can specify SQL behavior with column mapping:

http://grails.org/doc/2.4.3/ref/Database%20Mapping/column.html